# How to change chart axis type to include only existing data

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to change the chart axis on a scatter plot chart so that Excel doesn't fill in missing dates (my data table has missing weekend dates).  However, I cannot do that through the UI in Axis options.  I had two scenarios:

1. For one chart, the option to change the Axis type to `Date axis` in the formatting windows that appears, however clicking that radio button doesn't do anything.  After leaving and re-entering the interface, the option goes back to `Automatically select based on data`.
   [image: Chart 1 Options]
2. The option doesn't exist on another scatter plot I have.  When I enter the Axis options in the interface, there is no option to change the Axis Type for the second chart.  In fact it is quite different.
   [image: Chart 2 Options]

So I tried to change the Axis type using VBA.  I found that this line of code should work (based on macro recorder and Microsoft Docs).  `cht` is a valid chart object referring to an existing chart

```
cht.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlTimeScale
```

I doesn't do anything on the second chart, no issues running though.  However, when run using the first chart(the one where the radio button to change the axis type appears), I'm thrown this error

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)'
>
> Parameter not valid

Which seems strange since the macro recorder agrees with the line of code.

Additionally, Microsoft states here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.axis.categorytype

> You cannot set this property for a value axis.

While in the example, they clearly set the `CategoryType` property to something else.

So in essence, I need to format the chart to contain only the data I have in the data source range and nothing else.  I tried Excel's UI and VBA, but they don't work and are contradictory.

Does anyone have a solution to format these charts?

Also, if someone can explain these weird property behaviours, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

CategoryType is only valid for the X axis, that is, the horizontal axis of a line chart, area chart, or column chart or the vertical axis of a bar chart. The X axis of an XY scatter chart, like the Y axis, is a numeric axis.

If you choose a date scale axis, Excel will fill in dates. It's almost like a numerical axis, in that if you have some numbers (like 1,2,4,5) the axis contains any numbers in between (like 3). If you want weekend dates to be omitted, you have to choose xlCategoryScale.